# How do I take the variance of a subset of a vector?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use dplyr to create summary statistics over different groups of the data.

Let's say for group 1:
`variable1 <- c(4,51,100,200,10)`

And I want code something along these lines:

```
library(dplyr)

summaryVars <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean, var, limited_var = var(if variable1 > 50))
```

How can I return `limited_var = var(c(51,100,200))`

Comment: Can you show  `df`?

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to use `mutate` instead of `summarise`, and use `slice` at the end, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

#Creating a toy data set
df <- data.frame(variable1 = c(4, 51, 100, 200, 10), iris, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
    group_by(Species) %>% 
    filter(row_number() == 1:5) %>% 
    ungroup()

str(df)
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':  15 obs. of  6 variables:
 #$ variable1   : num  4 51 100 200 10 4 51 100 200 10 ...
 #$ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 7 6.4 6.9 5.5 6.5 ...
 #$ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.2 3.2 3.1 2.3 2.8 ...
 #$ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 4.7 4.5 4.9 4 4.6 ...
 #$ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 1.4 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.5 ...
 #$ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...


df %>% 
 group_by(Species) %>% 
 mutate(limited_var = var(variable1[variable1 > 50])) %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(-limited_var), funs(mean, var)) %>% 
 slice(1L) %>%
 ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is all you need to answer my question:

```
limited_var = var(variable1[variable1 > 50])
```

use that within dplyr to calculate the variance for a subset of the group.